# How to call ajax with in another ajax call using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here once we enter a tag in text  box, the images,titles and tags will be displayed,that should be fine.Once we enter any hyper link,that tag associated images,titles and tags should  be displayed.Can any once help me how we can call ajax with in another ajax call.
Here is my code.

```
$('#idSubmit').click(function(){  
  $('#image-container').html("");  
   var txtVal = $('#idText').val(); 
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags="+txtVal,
            data:"&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
            success:function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {      
                    if (item.media.m){
                        var container = $("<div/>");                        
                        var tagImgs = $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(container);
                        var imgTitle = $("<p/>").html('<b>Title</b> : ' + item.title).appendTo(container)
                        var imgTags = $("<p/>").html('<b>Tags</b> : ' + item.tags).appendTo(container);                                                                             
                        var imgTags1 = item.tags;
                        var imgTags1 = imgTags1.split(' ');                     
                        $.each(imgTags1, function( index, value ) {                                             
                           $('<span style="padding-left:4px;"/>').html($("<a>"+imgTags1[index]+"</a>").attr("href", imgTags1[index])).appendTo(container).click(function(data){
                              alert($(this).text());
                              displayTagImages(data);
                           });                                               
                        });                 
                        $("#image-container").append( container);                        
                        if (i == 9) return false;
                    }                   
                });
            },
            dataType:'jsonp'
       });
  });

function displayTagImages(data){
 var txtVal = data; 
 $('#idSubmit').click(function(){  
  $('#image-container').html("");    
    $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags="+txtVal,
            data:"&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
            success:function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {      
                    if (item.media.m){
                        var container = $("<div/>");                        
                        var tagImgs = $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(container);
                        var imgTitle = $("<p/>").html('<b>Title</b> : ' + item.title).appendTo(container)
                        var imgTags = $("<p/>").html('<b>Tags</b> : ' + item.tags).appendTo(container);                                                                                 
                        var imgTags1 = item.tags;
                        var imgTags1 = imgTags1.split(' ');                     
                        $.each(imgTags1, function( index, value ) {                                             
                           $('<span style="padding-left:4px;"/>').html($("<a>"+imgTags1[index]+"</a>").attr("href", imgTags1[index])).appendTo(container);                                           
                        });                 
                        $("#image-container").append( container);                        
                        if (i == 9) return false;
                    }                   
                });
            },
            dataType:'jsonp'
       });
  });
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3vYW/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your point, but try this:

```
$('#idSubmit').click(function() {

    displayTagImages($('#idText').val());
});

function displayTagImages(data) {

    var txtVal = data;
    $('#idText').val(data);
    $('#image-container').html("");
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=" + txtVal,
        data : "&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        success : function(data) {

            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {

                if (item.media.m) {
                    var container = $("<div/>");
                    var tagImgs = $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo(container);
                    var imgTitle = $("<p/>").html('<b>Title</b> : ' + item.title).appendTo(container)
                    var imgTags = $("<p/>").html('<b>Tags</b> : ' + item.tags).appendTo(container);
                    var imgTags1 = item.tags;
                    var imgTags1 = imgTags1.split(' ');
                    $.each(imgTags1, function(index, value) {

                        var txt =  imgTags1[index] ;
                        $('<span style="padding-left:4px;"/>').html($("<a>" + imgTags1[index] + "</a>").attr("href", imgTags1[index])).appendTo(
                                container).click(function(data) {

                            displayTagImages(txt);
                            return false;
                        });

                    });
                    $("#image-container").append(container);
                    if (i == 9)
                        return false;
                }
            });
        },
        dataType : 'jsonp'
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/r3vYW/4/